# How to catch Cntrl + C in a shell script which runs a Python script

Tags: python, shell

I'm trying to write a simple program which runs a Python program and inspects the resulting output file:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm archived_sensor_data.json
python rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py
trap "gedit archived_sensor_data.json" 2
```

The Python script `rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py` runs indefinitely and writes (in append-only mode) to the file `archived_sensor_data.json`. In order to start on a 'clean slate' every time, I'd like to delete the file every time before running. Then after I interrupt the execution with Cntrl + C, I'd like to automatically trigger an opening of the file using Gedit.

The problem is that when I press Cntrl+C, it doesn't seem to open Gedit automatically. Is `2` not the right exit code to use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by capturing the signal inside `rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py` as follows:

```
#!/usr/env/bin python

try:
    # your existing code here---let's assume it does the following:

    import time
    outfile = open( "archived_sensor_data.json", "wt" )  # NB: this already does the job of erasing previous content
    while True:
        outfile.write( "There's a horse in aisle five.\n" )
        time.sleep( 1 )
        outfile.write( "My house is full of traps.\n" )
        time.sleep( 1 )

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print( "You pressed Ctrl-C" )
```

...and the wrapper script would then simply be:

```
#!/bin/bash

python rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py
gedit archived_sensor_data.json
```

But really, why bother with the wrapper, when you could do it all in the Python, replacing the final `print()` call as follows:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    os.execlp("gedit", "archived_sensor_data.json")
```

...and then just call the Python script directly from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import signal
    import os
    os.system("rm archived_sensor_data.json")
    def signal_handler(signal, frame):
            print('You pressed Ctrl+C!')
            os.system("gedit archived_sensor_data.json")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    #your remaining code
    #must be placed here
```

Just run your code using following command
$ python rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py

This must solve your problem

Read signal handler for more information

Answer (score 0):

The other answers involve modifying the Python code itself, which is less than ideal since I don't want it to contain code related only to the testing. Instead, I found that the following bash script useful:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm archived_sensor_data.json
python rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py ; gedit archived_sensor_data.json
```

This will run the `gedit archived_sensor_data.json` command after `python rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py` is finished, regardless of whether it exited successfully.

Comment: Instead of modifying the original Python file, you could always have wrapped it with a second Python file, which would include the `except KeyboardInterrupt` clause after a `try: execfile('rethinkdb_monitor_batch.py')`